# difference between /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf and /applications/xampp/xamppfiles/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

Tags: macos, apache, virtualhost

10 and xampp 5.6.3 and I try to make a virtual host, but i see two different files : httpd-vhosts.conf .Which file should be changed ? And what is the difference between them ?

Comment: I don't know ,but  when I change one of them in  another one I didn't see the changes and this confuses me

Comment: One file is for native OS X apache, the other one is for `xampp` apache. If you use `xampp` modify the latter.